# Dominant speaker in OpenTok/Vonage Video API

Tags: opentok

I don't see any explicit features for a dominant speaker event in the Vonage/OpenTok web SDK, however I do see they have an event called AudioLevelUpdatedEvent that could be used to determine a dominant speaker. I'm wondering if there are any code examples already out there for this so I don't have reinvent the wheel.

Comment: It looks like they don't have much of a code sample [other than this one](https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/customize-ui/js/#active_speaker), and the [guidance in this blog post](https://www.nexmo.com/blog/2020/07/23/best-practices-for-multi-party-video-conferencing-with-the-vonage-video-api-dr#post-green:~:text=Active%20Speaker%20Detection%20%26%20Layout%20Management). If you find something better, or have already implemented a solution, would you mind letting me know?

Answer (score 1):

This is old, so I hope you found your answer, but writing this here for anyone else.

I worked in Video Express, a JS SDK designed to add a lot of functionality on top of the core Video API. It provides this functionality as part of a built-in layout manager but is constrained to meetings use-cases where as the core Video API can be used on anything from fitness equipment to autonomous vehicles. If you're comfortable with the assumption that everyone has both a display and a camera, and each person in the session should publish as well as view, check out https://tokbox.com/developer/video-express/

If you wanted to develop your own layout, the underlying code is exposed in the page @evan.bovie shared about audioLevelUpdated in the developer portal. https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/customize-ui/js/#active_speaker

We found that a 300ms to one second delay is about right to determine speaking versus random noise, and to cut down on dizzying swaps to new speakers in fast exchanges. If someone is speaking for more than 1 second, the below code identifies the new speaker and prints a console message. You of course can take action in the UI however you see fit.

For example, this code can be used to draw a border around whomever is talking, or in concert with `setPreferredResolution()` to prioritize the speaker's video and enlarge it in the UI.
https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/Subscriber.html#setPreferredResolution

```
var subscriber = session.subscribe(event.stream);

SpeakerDetection(subscriber, function() {
  console.log('started talking');
}, function() {
  console.log('stopped talking');
});

var SpeakerDetection = function(subscriber, startTalking, stopTalking) {
  var activity = null;
  subscriber.on('audioLevelUpdated', function(event) {
    var now = Date.now();
    if (event.audioLevel > 0.2) {
      if (!activity) {
        activity = {timestamp: now, talking: false};
      } else if (activity.talking) {
        activity.timestamp = now;
      } else if (now- activity.timestamp > 1000) {
        // detected audio activity for more than 1s
        // for the first time.
        activity.talking = true;
        if (typeof(startTalking) === 'function') {
          startTalking();
        }
      }
    } else if (activity && now - activity.timestamp > 3000) {
      // detected low audio activity for more than 3s
      if (activity.talking) {
        if (typeof(stopTalking) === 'function') {
          stopTalking();
        }
      }
      activity = null;
    }
  });
};
```